# How to prevent input from cutting tails of the letters without changing the height?

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve an input field with an underline. As it is visually more appealing to me, I'm trying to make underline as close as possible to the font. I did achieve the closeness, but now, input field cuts tail parts of the letters with tails. Is there a possible workaround for this? Can I cancel input's this behaviour with something like "overflow: visible"? Or may I draw a fake line over the input field, instead of using border-bottom? Thanks in advance.

In short, I'm trying to make text get through the bottom line.

Here is a screenshoot about the problem.

[image]

Here is my current class:

```
.kk_input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use more than one box-shadow to create this effect.

```css
.so49204829_input{
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -11px 0 #fff, inset 0 -12px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="so49204829_input">
```

& here's another approach using a second element. Unfortunately, you can't add an `:after` pseudo-element to input elements (at the time of posting).

```css
.so49204829_input {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  width: 200px;
  display:block;
}

.so49204829_input_accent {
  margin-top: -14px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 208px;
  background-color: #000;
  pointer-events: none; /* this makes sure click events aren't intercepted by the accent-line element */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="so49204829_input"><div class="so49204829_input_accent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, as this is a single element, I found this more useful than @mindlis's.

Comment: @Belial Np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the rest of your markup, this should give you an idea enough to go off of.

```css
.kk_input {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="kk_input" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood and will edit if so.  Are you trying to get the text to go through the bottom line?

Comment: Not a problem and yes, I was going to write that. My goal is to get the text to get through the bottom line. :)

Comment: Updated my answer for that

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for how to do this, but as I'm not familiar with positions, I couldn't manage to do that.

edit: As @admcfajn's suggestion is more useful, I accepted his. Still, thanks again.

Comment: Looks like we were in a race, sorry to duplicate your answer in mine. I was elaborating at the same time as you were.

Comment: No worries, looks like you covered all the bases